# Qt Qml like vars in js

Tags: javascript, qt, variables

This is just a general question.
I have seen a few implementations of code kind of like this but not quite. 
So in qt creator if I define two properties like so

```
property int othervar: 3;
property int val: 1 + othervar;
```

then the property 'val' will re-evaluate its self when 'othervar' gets changed in any way.

If I was to re-write something like this to work in js how might I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications and bindings work only for QML properties, there is no such functionality readily available in JS. You can emulate it, but it will take some extra syntax. It will not be elegant and convenient.

While it is possible to implement signals, and incorporate them by using setter functions instead of the `=` operator, the actual binding expressions will be tricky. This happens automatically in QML, if you'd do it manually, you'd have to manually connect the notify signal of every value used in the particular expression to a function that reevaluates it. It would be fairly easy for trivial expression like in the question, but for anything complex it is just not applicable.

So in short:

> If I was to re-write something like this to work in js how might I go
>   about this?

You mightn't! It requires support at "language" level. Such things are not even available in Qt from C++, they are facilitated by QML.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I was thinking of ways that I could do it and it would mean giving each and ever variable a pubs and subs object. but the part im not sure about is two things. If i did that with each string, int, bool etc what would that be like for memory? would it be way to much for the js heap to handle? and secondly

Comment: when we init a var for eg'var val1 = val2; i could set the pubs and subs event with in the pubs and subs object of val2 to update each of the subscribers etc when the value is changed, but once again i wasn't sure if the '=' assignment event was event possible to get even if i wrote my own Object.prototypes. And lastly im no js expert by far. I love qt and im wanting to bring some implementation to the broswer.

Comment: @TheMan68 - I am not exactly a JS wizz myself, I know only very basic stuff. You may want to ask another question targeted at the JS crowd. Also this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692174/can-i-make-a-variables-value-depend-on-changes-to-another-variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so in a QtQuick context, you have basically two ways to handle it. Binding are nicely explained on [Qt bindings documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html).

1. With a property "changed" signal handler

   ```
   Item {
       property int othervar: 3

       onOthervarChanged: {
           // Update val
           jsObject.val = 1 + othervar;
       }
   }
   ```
2. By creating a binding from Javascript on an existing property

   ```
   Item {
       property int othervar: 3
       property int val: 0

       Component.onCompleted: {
           // Create a binding dynamically
           val = Qt.binding(function() { return 1 + othervar })
       }
   }
   ```

It is important to note that when assiging to a property that previously had a binding, for example by doing `val = 3`, the existing binding is removed, and the value will no more be updated automatically.

Comment: HI there again. Sorry that I haven't gotten back to you. 
You have slightly mis understood my question. 
What I mean was if I wanted to implement my own version in javascript with some vars like this then what might an implementation look like?

Comment: for eg: var val = some type of object that would update its own value like qml vars