# How to update a variable that depends on another variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

In the sample code below, note that the value of the variable `dependent` depends on the variable `prereq`. When the function `changePrereq` is called, it changes the value of `prereq`. This change is shown if logged, but it isn't reflected in the value of `dependent`. Instead, when `dependent` is put into a span, it shows `Some text - undefined`.

How can I have `dependent` change depending on the value of `prereq`?

P.S. Thanks everyone for the advice. For myself, I chose the answer from **"[ztcollazo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13582829/ztcollazo)"** as the right decision.

**"[outis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90527/outis)"** - Thank you for your explanations. I will definitely pay attention to your recommendations and study them in more detail!

```js
var display = document.getElementById('text'),
    prereq,
    message = "Some text - " + prereq;

function updateDisplay() {
    display.innerHTML = message;
    console.log(prereq);
}

function changePrereq() {
    prereq = "I am some text.";
    updateDisplay();
}
```

```html
<p><span id="text"></span></p>
<button onclick="changePrereq()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Did you mean `if (m1 > 0)`? `m` is a string, not a number, so it doesn't make sense to compare it with `0`.

Comment: You've never assigned anything to `someText1`. What should `"Some text - " + someText1` be?

Comment: Actually @Barmar the changeMyText is a global var defined up and m is an argument to the function changeTextFunc, I think the changeMyText variable gets added with undefined because someText1 is not defined at the time of usage. Though I agree it's a very confusing piece of code :D

Comment: @Icepickle I already deleted that comment since I misread it.

Comment: But it definitely looks like there is something missing here, so my vote to close for lacking details is there :)

Comment: The all-to-similar names `changeText`, `changeTextFunc` and `changeMyText` make the code harder to understand. Pick your names to more accurately describe what they name for better readability.

Comment: See also "[Can I make a variable's value depend on changes to another variable (sometimes after a delay)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23692174/90527)".

Comment: Note the global `m` did nothing. It and other extraneous code was removed to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `changeMyText` doesn't update when `someText` does. You need to define `changeMyText` inside of the `changeTextFunc` function and then pass `someText` as a parameter.

Example:

```js
var myText = document.getElementById('text');
var someText1;

var m1 = 1;

function changeTextFunc(someText, m) {
  var changeMyText = "Some text - " + someText;
  if (m > 0) {
    myText.innerHTML = changeMyText;
  } else {
    console.log('m < 0');
  }
}

function changeText() {
  someText1 = "I a'm some text.";
  changeTextFunc(someText1, m1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="changeText()">Click</button>
  <p id="text"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

move changeMyText variable into changeTextFunc function.
the code will looks like this

```
    function changeMyText(m){
          var changeMyText = "Some text - " + someText1;
          if (m > 0) {
             myText.innerHTML = changeMyText;
          } else {
             console.log('m < 0');
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable to change based on another, you must set its value after the other is changed. There are various approaches, with various implementations. You can break it down into different aspects for the change:

1. what:

   1. globals (note: [avoid global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) in production, and use sparingly in other contexts for the practice)
   2. locals
   3. objects

      1. plain methods
      2. [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)/[setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_getters_and_setters)
2. where:

   1. inline, at the site a variable is referred to
   2. in a separate function created for the responsibility
3. when:

   1. the prerequisite variable is changed
   2. the dependent variable is used

Some of the above options from different aspects aren't intended to be combined, or can't be combined. For example, 1.3 (objects) is intended to go with 2.2 (separate functions), and 1.3.2 (getters/setters) requires 2.2, since object getters & setters are functions (2.2 basically means "use a getter or setter", though not necessarily using getter/setter syntax). You might be able to think of other aspects, or other possibilities for the above aspects.

ztcollazo shows a solution that uses a global for the prerequisite (1.1), a local for the dependent (1.2) and updates inline (2.1) when the dependent is used (3.2). If the line in `changeTextFunc` setting `changeMyText` were instead move to `changeText` (and a global used), you'd have 1.1 + 2.1 + 3.1.

For some more example implementations, examine the following. It illustrates four different options from the above, noted by comments.

```js
var display = document.getElementById('output'),
    dependent, prereq;

/* options 1.1, 2.2, 3.1: global, separate function, prereq change */
function setPrereq(value) {
    prereq = value;
    dependent = "global prereq setter: " + prereq;
}

function updateDisplayFromVariable() {
    display.innerText = dependent;
}

function changePrereq_updateWhenSet(value="setter") {
    setPrereq(value);
    updateDisplayFromVariable();
}

/* options 1.1, 2.2, 3.2: global, separate function, dependent used */
function getDependent(value) {
    return dependent = "global dependent getter: " + prereq;
}

function updateDisplayFromGetter() {
    display.innerText = getDependent();
}

function changePrereq_updateWhenUsed(value="inline, no setter") {
    prereq = value;
    updateDisplayFromGetter();
}

/* options 1.3.2, 2.2: (local) object getter/setter */
/* wrapped in self-called function to prevent polluting global namespace */
var dependency = (function () {
    let display = document.getElementById('output'),

        /* options 1.3.2, 2.2, 3.2: (local) object getter, dependent used */
        inGetter = {
            prereq: 'initial',
            /* note: `dependent` is entirely synthetic */
            get dependent() {
                return "object's dependent getter: " + this.prereq;
            },
        },

        /* options 1.3.2, 2.2, 3.1: (local) object setter, prereq changed */
        inSetter = {
            /* note: when using setter, can't use same name for the 
             * backing property; instead, must also define getter. */
            _prereq: 'initial',
            get prereq() {
                return this._prereq;
            },
            set prereq(value) {
                this._prereq = value;
                this.dependent = "object's prereq setter: " + value;
            },
        };

    function updateDisplay(from) {
        display.innerText = from.dependent;
    }
    
    /* expose 1.3.2, 2.2, 3.1 */
    function whenSet(value) {
        inSetter.prereq = value;
        updateDisplay(inSetter);
    }
    
    /* expose 1.3.2, 2.2, 3.2 */
    function whenUsed(value) {
        inGetter.prereq = value;
        updateDisplay(inGetter);
    }

    return {whenSet, whenUsed};
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="changePrereq_updateWhenSet('thimbles')">Use global setter</button>
<button onclick="changePrereq_updateWhenUsed('care')">Use global getter</button>
<button onclick="dependency.whenSet('forks')">Use object setter</button>
<button onclick="dependency.whenUsed('hope')">Use object getter</button>
<p><span id="output"></span></p>
```

As with any design, the above have advantages and disadvantages, but using object setters/getters (1.3.2) should be preferred, as it's the most robust approach. Using standalone functions (not getters/setters) and updating inline are both more brittle as a programmer may fail to use them somewhere, instead assigning & referencing variables directly. Updating inline is also less maintainable, as any changes will have to be made on every line that performs the update. Global variables have their own issues, such as:

- limited code reuse in a module (note how `updateDisplay(from)` works for two different cases, whereas `changePrereq_updateWhenSet` and `changePrereq_updateWhenUsed` each require different display functions), and
- inflexibility (i.e. composing existing functions for new behaviors is much more limited; in other words, this limits code reuse for client code),
- naming collisions when different modules use the same globals, causing them to stomp on each other.

As for whether to update the dependent in the prerequisite's setter (1.3.2 + 2.2 + 3.1) or to use a getter for the dependent with no backing property (in some circles, this is known as a "synthetic property") depends on other requirements (basically, whether the dependent be allowed to be assigned values independent of the prerequisite). You could, for instance, use getters & setters for both properties.